# c# getting list of custom events of an object

Tags: c#, events, attributes

I want to create a base class with the following functionality:
The base class will host an object which may have some custom events. I want each of the custom events to be handled in the base class such that when they are raised, it will invoke an event in the base class.
Is this possible?

I've tried doing this by attaching a custom attribute to the events and then in the base class trying to get hold of all the events with this attribute but am unsure how to proceed here.

```
public class cls
{
    [cAttr]
    public event Action event1;
}

public class cm
{
        var c = new cls();
        var atrs = typeof(cls).GetCustomAttributes(true);
        foreach (var atr in atrs)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(atr.ToString());
        }
 }
```

At this point my atrs variable returns no custom attributes whereas I am expecting to get event1.

I would appreciate some help getting hold of the events and also any suggestions if this mechanism of handling events could be improved.

Thanks

Comment: So does the object extend from the base-class or is the base class independent to the hosted object? because if it is independent like in your example above, you could make a base-class and the hostet object could inherit the base class. This approche would make it easier to handle the events.

Comment: the object is indeed independent. making a base class consisting of events for each of the hosted objects is a little tricky as some of the objects are already derived from a base class...